Error when trying to install dependencies of a cloned react native app
After cloning from git using the command:
git clone https://github.com/Rish7223/NativeShop.git

I tried to install dependencies using the command:
npm install

but got the error message:

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency
tree npm ERR!  npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined npm ERR!
Found: react@17.0.1 npm ERR! node_modules/react npm ERR!
react@"17.0.1" from the root project npm ERR!  npm ERR! Could not
resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0" from
@react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.10   npm ERR!
node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view npm ERR!
@react-native-community/masked-view@"0.1.10" from the root project npm
ERR! npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR!
this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an
incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR! npm
ERR! npm ERR! For a full report see: npm ERR!
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-04-02T09_53_03_751Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-04-02T09_53_03_751Z-debug-0.log

I deleted the node module file and paackage-lock.json file then retried :
then got the message again:

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency
tree npm ERR!  npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined npm ERR!
Found: react@17.0.1 npm ERR! node_modules/react npm ERR!
react@"17.0.1" from the root project npm ERR!  npm ERR! Could not
resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0" from
@react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.10   npm ERR!
node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view npm ERR!
@react-native-community/masked-view@"0.1.10" from the root project npm
ERR! npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR!
this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an
incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR! npm
ERR! npm ERR! For a full report see: npm ERR!
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-04-02T09_53_03_751Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-04-02T09_53_03_751Z-debug-0.log


Do you have npm installed? You can check that via npm -v command.

try yarn install

i deleted node-modules directory and package-lock.json file before trying:
yarn install                                                                                                                                but i still got the error  message
error Can't add "@types/prop-types": invalid package version undefined.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command

i also checked and was sure that npm was installed

did you tried the flag --legacy-peer-deps, when running npm install? this might happens sometimes when we've got some conflict in the dependencies and using the flag --legacy-peer-deps would be a temporary fix for that, untill you find the peer dependencies of a library and resolve them.
